# Define an object as subtype of a generic sealed class?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
sealed class SubscriptionServiceResponse<T>
data class UserRecognized<T>(val recognizedUser: RecognizedUser, val response: T) : SubscriptionServiceResponse<T>()
data class UserNotRecognized<T>(val ignored: Boolean = true) : SubscriptionServiceResponse<T>()
```

However, I'd prefer `UserNotRecognized` to just be an `object` - something like:

```
object UserNotRecognized : SubscriptionServiceResponse()
```

(The `ignored` parameter is just there because I can't make a data class without any parameters).

Is there any way to define an `object` as the subtype of a generic `sealed class`?

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? Your example seems fine to me

Comment: The version where `UserNotRecognized` is an `object` doesn't compile - and as I said, I really don't need any _content_ in that case, the `Boolean` is just there to satisfy the compiler...

Comment: Is the generic type of your object important for the logic? Or is `Any` type enough?

Comment: Yeah, for the `UserRecognized` case it _is_ important - I'd like to have `UserRecognized<SubscriptionStatus>`, `UserRecognized<PurchaseOptions>`, etc.

Comment: Ok, maybe I got this wrong, but the type of your UserNotRecognized isn't very important, as you're not treating it as useful data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Any` or `Any?`, ignoring the generic type for the non-response only. As from your question, I understood that you're not caring about the generic type of your object, so maybe you can not care about it at all

Something like this:

```
sealed class SubscriptionServiceResponse<T> {
    data class UserRecognized<T>(val bool: Boolean) : SubscriptionServiceResponse<T>()
    object UserNotRecognized : SubscriptionServiceResponse<Any?>()
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes - thanks! In fact I had tried that yesterday but the following still did not compile: `fun someResponse() : SubscriptionServiceResponse<String> = UserNotRecognized` - however if I write it like this: `fun someResponse() : SubscriptionServiceResponse<String> = UserNotRecognized as SubscriptionServiceResponse<String>`, everything's fine!

Comment: If you declare `sealed class SubscriptionServiceResponse<in T>`, the cast is not required.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Perfect, that's the missing piece! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the generic type like this:

```
object UserNotRecognized : SubscriptionServiceResponse<Any>()
```